# Array merging and sorting complexity calculation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

I have one exercise from my algorithm text book and I am not really sure about the solution. I need to explain why this solution:

```
function array_merge_sorted(array $foo, array $bar)
{
  $baz = array_merge($foo, $bar);
  $baz = array_unique($baz);
  sort($baz);

  return $baz;
}
```

that merge two array and order them is not the most efficient and I need to provide one solution that is the most optimized and prove that not better solution can be done.

My idea was about to use a mergesort algorithm that is O(n log n), to merge and order the two array passed as parameter. But how can I prove that is the best solution ever?

Comment: You first need to prove the lower bound for merging and sorting. You can find a solution and explanation by searching on the web, it is a very theoretical argument arguing about the amount of comparisons that need to be made in order to find the ordering. After that you need to find an algorithm which has this complexity. Just as a question, is anything known about the two arrays? For example if they are already sorted? Then the ideal algorithm uses a *zipper-like* approach by processing both arrays at the same time, always inserting the lower element of both lists and so on `O(n)`.

Comment: the two arrays parameters are sorted

Comment: Mergesort works in `O(n log n)` which would be one of the optimal solutions for sorting as the lower bound for comparison-based sorting algorithms is in `Omega(n log n)` ([see also](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/lowerbounden.htm)). However I don't know how your additional requirement of **merging** two arrays **and sorting** them comes into play there.

Comment: Which could be the best optimized solution to merge and order two ordered arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Algorithm

As you have said that **both inputs are already sorted**, you can use a simple **zipper-like** approach.

You have one pointer for each input array, pointing to the begin of it. Then you compare both elements, adding the smaller one to the result and advancing the pointer of the array with the smaller element. Then you repeat the step until both pointers reached the end and all elements where added to the result.

You find a collection of such algorithms at [Wikipedia#Merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) with my current presented approach being listed as **Merging two lists**.

Here is some *pseudocode*:

```
function Array<Element> mergeSorted(Array<Element> first, Array<Element> second) {
    Array<Element> result = new Array<Element>(first.length + second.length);
    int firstPointer = 0;
    int secondPointer = 0;

    while (firstPointer < first.length && secondPointer < first.length) {
        Element elementOfFirst = first.get(firstPointer);
        Element elementOfSecond = second.get(secondPointer);

        if (elementOfFirst < elementOfSecond) {
            result.add(elementOfFirst);
            firstPointer = firstPointer + 1;
        } else {
            result.add(elementOfSecond);
            secondPointer = secondPointer + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Proof

The algorithm obviously works in `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the resulting list. Or more precise it is `O(max(n, n')` with `n` being the size of the first list and `n'` of the second list (or `O(n + n')` which is the same set).

This is also obviously **optimal** since you need, at some point, at least traverse **all elements** once in order to build the result and know the final ordering. This yields a lower bound of `Omega(n)` for this problem, thus the algorithm is optimal.

---

A more formal proof assumes a better **arbitrary** algorithm `A` which solves the problem **without** taking a look at **each element** at least **once** (or more precise, with less than `O(n)`).

We call that element, which the algorithm does not look at, `e`. We can now construct an input `I` such that `e` has a value which fulfills the order in its own array but will be placed wrong by the algorithm in the resulting array.

We are able to do so for every algorithm `A` and since `A` always needs to work correctly on all possible inputs, we are able to find a counter-example `I` such that it fails.

Thus `A` **can not exist** and `Omega(n)` is a **lower bound** for that problem.

---

### Why the given algorithm is worse

Your given algorithm first merges the two arrays, this works in `O(n)` which is good. But after that it sorts the array.

Sorting (more precise: comparison-based sorting) has a lower-bound of `Omega(n log n)`. This means every such algorithm can not be better than that.

Thus the given algorithm has a total time complexity of `O(n log n)` (because of the sorting part). Which is **worse than** `O(n)`, the complexity of the other algorithm and also the optimal solution.

---

However, to be super-correct, we also would need to argue whether the **sort**-method truly yields that complexity, since it does not get arbitrary inputs but always the result of the **merge**-method. Thus it could be possible that a **specific sorting method** works especially good for such specific inputs, yielding `O(n)` in the end.

But I doubt that this is in the focus of your task.

Comment: Perfect solution. Just two question for you: 1. I didn't get your proof to show that this algorithm is optimal saying "This yields a lower bound of Omega(n) for this problem, thus the algorithm is optimal.".

Comment: 2.how I solve the problem of duplicate values? for example if I have number 3 in both arrays?

Comment: 2: The current pseudo-code treats `equal` as **else-case** but you can arbitrarily choose one, it does not matter. Just make sure to always add all elements in the end (as long as you don't want to have a `Set` in the end).

Comment: 1: How should you be able to build a new array which contains `n` elements with less than `n` iterations. And also, how should you be able to find the correct order for all elements without taking a look at **each element** at least once. For every algorithm that does **not look at each element** you can construct an input where the algorithm yields a wrong result. Therefore you only need to manipulate the element, which the algorithm does not look at, such that the algorithm places it wrong. You proof that by exactly that kind of counter-proof for all arbitrary algorithms that are *faster*.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just two more questions and after that I have really finished to bother. This solution is O(n) that is better than O(n log n) right?And to come back to the topic of this post, why the code I have posted above it is not the best optimization?I suppose because it first merge,after make the array uniques values and after sort

Comment: Good question. I included it in my answer.

Comment: Excellent!Thanks so much!

Comment: One note: I think that when we have same values in both arrays the pointer of both should be increased

Comment: Possible, but then you also need to add **both elements**, or your will filter out **duplicates**. However the current approach also works, the other element will then be added in the next iteration.

Comment: i think with your approach you dupliacte the value in resulting array

Comment: Yes but if your input is `[1, 1]` and `[1, 1]`, the expected result is `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, isn't it? At least that is what the current form of the algorithm produces. However I think at this point you can easily adjust it to fit your specific needs :)